# Cannot install packages in my virtualbox machine

Tags: 16.04, apt, virtualbox, lubuntu

I have just installed Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS in my virtualbox machine, but I cannot install any new packages? I tried to remove source lists, and update but the same probleme was repeted.
I tried this commandes line but ths same probleme.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

Output of update is :

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'fr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'fr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'fr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'fr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'fr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'fr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thanks in advence

Comment: What output did you get from `sudo apt-get update` as no output shows a problem as you have no sources available. (FYI: You've tagged `lubuntu` which is EOL for 16.04 LTS, only Ubuntu server (no desktop), Ubuntu desktop (Unity 7), Kylin or Ubuntu Core 16 are still supported, all flavors are EOL.  The output from `sudo apt-get update` is where I'd look first for clues though.

Comment: Please don't provide additional information in comments, edit your question and add extra detail there. Greater formatting is allowed in questions/answers, it's easier to read etc....

Comment: You have a temporary network issue, which on a VM usually means problems with the host setup in my experience (it's disabled, wrongly configured, etc).  It could also be you're behind firewalls, proxy ....  but I'd check your host first.

Answer (score 1):

It seems is just a stupid mistake I have done, I'have forgot to add DNS server name in my interfaces configurations, so all my packages can't resolves a domaine names.

Solution was :adding the line

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

on the file `/etc/network/interfaces`